# How can I open a safari link from standalone webapp?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios-standalone-mode

I'm trying to open an html page (I get it as a `string` and parse it) from my fullscreen iOS web application (standalone).

I tried opening a window (`window.open`) but it doesn't work.

It involves handling a payment method, so I can't redirect back from their page to mine (it's an illegal hack) when I finish.

How can I manage opening the html file in safari and going back?

Comment: It would be helpful if you narrowed your question and clarified it. When you say 'it doesn't work' what do you mean? What behavior do you expect, and what do you actually see? The payment handling part is unclear: you should explain the flow and better define where you're running into an obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way that a standalone mode web app can serve up raw HTML to the user without it being hosted somewhere.

If you have a genuine web URL though, you can have the user click a link with `target="_blank"` (new tab) and it should open in Safari, instead of the standalone browser. I don't think you can do it via window.open(), because it will be silently blocked as a "pop-up".